# Bugsnag catching errors in Vue Components

Tags: vue.js, bugsnag

I am trying to integrate bugsnag into my Vue app and I'm following the bugsnag-vue [docs](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/browsers/vue/#bundled).  I can see uncaught errors reported if they happened during vue lifecycle methods (mounted, beforeDestroy, etc) but if they happen during a normal method they are not caught.  Is this normal behavior? The documentation seems to say all errors will be caught, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Am I missing something?

Comment: What error is not caught? Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Not sure I can provide a great example with a fiddle, but if you clone their example project and modify the HelloWorld component to simply throw instead of notify within a Try/Catch block the error is not caught. 
Everything else works as expected. Throwing during lifecycle hooks is caught, this just isn't. https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-vue/blob/master/examples/bundled/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: Please update the question description with this new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing something that was pretty obvious in retrospect. You have to use [sourcemaps](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/browsers/faq/#4-code-generated-with-eval-e-g-from-webpack) correctly.  I didn't realize I was using 'cheap-eval-source-map' which won't work in this situations.  Changed the sourcemaps and everything worked as expected.